# PHP-DI Suddenly throws 'No entry or class found' error in production server

Tags: php, dependency-injection, php-di

I have a PayPal integration and for it, I have a Controller and Service class.

For the controller:

```
<?php

namespace App\Billing\Infrastructure\PayPal;

use App\Billing\Infrastructure\PayPal\PaypalService;
use App\Billing\Infrastructure\Provider\Interfaces\ProviderContract;
use App\Billing\Infrastructure\Provider\Traits\DirectResponseBuilder;

class PaypalTransaction implements ProviderContract
{
    use DirectResponseBuilder;

    private $service;

    public function __construct(PaypalService $service)
    {
        $this->service = $service;
    }
}
```

For the service class:

```
<?php
    
namespace App\Billing\Infrastructure\PayPal;

use PDO;
use App\Billing\Infrastructure\Provider\Interfaces\ProviderServiceContract;
use App\Billing\Infrastructure\Provider\Traits\ConfigBuilder;
use App\Billing\Infrastructure\Provider\Traits\RequestErrorHandler;
use App\Billing\Infrastructure\DirectResponsesRepository;
use App\Billing\Infrastructure\EpgLogger;
use GuzzleHttp\Client;
use App\Infrastructure\Config;

class PaypalService implements ProviderServiceContract
{
    use RequestErrorHandler;
    use ConfigBuilder;

    private $env;
    private $client;
    private $pdo;
    private $logger;
    private $responsesRepository;

    public function __construct(Config $env, Client $client, PDO $pdo, EpgLogger $logger, DirectResponsesRepository $responsesRepository)
    {
        $this->env = $env;
        $this->client = $client;
        $this->pdo = $pdo;
        $this->logger = $logger;
        $this->responsesRepository = $responsesRepository;
    }
}
```

Everything worked in my local development(I am using MAC btw, not sure if this info would be useful), but suddenly in the production/staging server, it throws error saying:

```
Slim Application Error
The application could not run because of the following error:

Details
Type: DI\DependencyException
Message: Error while injecting dependencies into App\Billing\Infrastructure\PayPal\PaypalTransaction: No entry or class found for 'App\Billing\Infrastructure\PayPal\PaypalService'
File: /var/www/zweeler.com/vendor/php-di/php-di/src/Definition/Resolver/ObjectCreator.php
```

I can also confirm that all the dependencies of `PaypalService` class is correct, as well as all the traits and interfaces of both  `PaypalService` and `PaypalTransaction`.

As of now, I ran out of ideas on why this happened.

Can anyone help?

Answer (score -1):

Are you sure you have included/required the necessary files? Class not found is a typical error in such scenarios

Is there a composer available for payPal? If yes, just update and ensure you are including the autoload file

Comment: I just knew. Symfony/Laravel uses PHP-DI, and the PHP file and the class name definition should be the same. For example, I have defined `class PaypalService` but I mistakenly have the filename `PayPalService.php`.